# find the partition and block device for a filesystem *without* string manipulation

Tags: bash, shell-script, filesystems

Given a filesystem such as `/dev/sda5` or `/dev/mmcblk0p5` is it possible to get both the partition number (`5`)  and block device (i.e. `/dev/mmcblk0`) without string manipulation, or by minimizing the amount of string parsing required?

Assume kernel 5.x.  Examples below are from a device running 5.10, however if an answer is kernel or config specific please call it out in your answer.

#### Details/ Examples:

`udevadm info` (in v247) gives back a lot of valuable information including a `PARTN` property.  *However* I don't believe there is a way to "print the value of property X." in v247 (in v251 possibly?)  So we would be relegated to parsing output to find our attribute and value like:

```
udevadm info /dev/disk/by-label/rootfs | grep -e '^E: PARTN=' | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'    # prints '2'
```

`udevadm` also includes `major` number which may help us later but no "disk" property or similar.

We can also find the partition number by reading the sysfs file `/sys/class/block/mmcblk0p2/partition` assuming we are content to strip the `/dev/` to leave us with `mmcblk0p2`:

```
$ cat /sys/class/block/mmcblk0p2/partition 
2
```

In the same fashion, it appears we can also get `major:minor` numbers (with minimal string tokenization):

```
$ cat /sys/class/block/mmcblk0p2/dev 
179:2
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be anything under `/sys/class/block/mmcblk0p2` that directly points to the block device where the partition resides, i.e. `mmcblk0` in this case.

To get the disk, we could search all paths under `/sys/block/` to find one that has our partition; i.e. does the path `/sys/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p2` exist? If yes, then the third path component i.e. `mmcblk0` is our disk.

Or we can use the `major` number from our partition (`179` in this case) like so:

```
$ realpath /dev/block/179\:0
/dev/mmcblk0
```

We could also parse `/proc/partitions` (again -- string parsing!)

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

..snip..
 179        0    7782400 mmcblk0
 179        1      96632 mmcblk0p1
 179        2    3145728 mmcblk0p2
```

Assuming some string finagling is going to be necessary, what's the "easiest" / least fragile method?

### Background

I have a generic ARM device image that supports multiple partition schemes. Some ARM devices require a particular partition scheme, while others might just use one partition. I have a script to expand the rootfs to fill the disk.

To resize the partition, we execute:

```
sfdisk --no-reread "$DISK" -N "$PART" <<EOF
, $SIZE, L
EOF
```

where, for instance, `DISK=/dev/mmcblk0` and `PART=2`.  Then we use `resize2fs` after that.

Comment: What's the benefit of avoiding string manipulation? Surely the difference in efficiency is negligible for something like this, so is it to ensure correctness?

Comment: Also, do you have a `/sys/class/block/mmcblk0/uevent` file? What does that have for `DEVNAME`?

Comment: Yes the goal is correctness not efficiency.  Simple string manipulation is OK but I want to avoid i.e. splitting `mmcblkXpY`  since it would be fragile and tied to the device naming scheme.

Comment: @terdon you are right, `/sys/class/block/$devname/uevent` contains many of the same useful properties that `udveadm info` gives

Answer (score 3):

> We could search all paths under /sys/block/ to find one that has our partition.

Instead of searching all paths, you could just read the symlink...

```
$ readlink /sys/class/block/sdb17
[…]/block/sdb/sdb17
$ basename "$(realpath /sys/class/block/sdb17/..)"
sdb
$ basename "$(realpath /sys/class/block/nvme0n1p2/..)"
nvme0n1
```

---

> Or we can use the major number from our partition (179 in this case) like so:

That fails for large partition numbers.

```
$ cat /sys/block/sdb/sdb17/dev
259:1
$ realpath /dev/block/259:0
/dev/sdb16
```

Comment: Not sure how your example shows it fails.

Comment: Not sure why you keep adding quotes. ;-)

Comment: Mostly because of [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) :-)

Comment: See also `echo /sys/class/block/sdb17/..(:P:t)` in `zsh`

Comment: Ah using the combination of '..' realpath and basename is clever! Also thank you for pointing out the limitation of major devuce number.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a udev rule, you can pass environment variables from it, to your script with arguments.

Where `%n` is the kernel number of the device (i.e `%n` from `/dev/sda1` gives you `1`).

And where `%P` is the node name of the parent device (i.e `%P` from `/dev/sda1` gives you `sda`). So you can prepend `%P` with `/dev` like `/dev/%P`, in your script to achieve your task.

So a short example of doing this would first be to create a udev rule (you would need to identify your device better than shown below):

```
KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/path/to/script.sh %P %n"
```

And then edit your script accordingly:

```
sfdisk --no-reread "/dev/$1" -N "$2" <<EOF
, $SIZE, L
EOF
```

Where `$1` would be `%P` and `$2` would be `%n`

Although this assumes that you want to run the script every time the device is inserted (due to `ACTION=="add"`). And this only works with scripts that doesn't take long to execute (udev doesn't handle long-running processes).

To bypass this you can pass the enviromental variable to a systemd instance unit, which then calls the script instead.

Comment: Actually the goal is to run this once from systemd on boot `Before=local-fs.target` also I've noticed `/dev/disk/by-label/rootfs` isn't necessarily created yet since that is a udev rule.